# RSA Archer - IF Statements - not returning any value

Tags: archer

I'm trying to use a calculated field to return the value in "Overall likelihood" field. The value returned by the Overall Likelihood fields depends on the values selected in "Likelihood of Occurrence" and "Likelihood of Adverse Impacts" fields. These values are selected by the users based on which the "Overall likelihood" field should be calculated.
The formula below gets validated but doesn't returns any value. Is there a problem with the way the logical operators are structured ? Please advise;

```
IF(

OR(

AND(

 [Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Almost    Certain"),
 [Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse  Impacts],"Rare")
),

 AND(
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Likely"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Rare")
),

 AND(
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Likely"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Unlikely")
),

 AND(
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Possible"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Unlikely")
),

AND (
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Possible"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Possible")
),

 AND(
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Unlikely"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Likely")
),

 AND(
     [Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Unlikely"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Possible")
),  

 AND(
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Rare"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Likely")
),

 AND(
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Rare"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Almost Certain")
)),

[Overall Likelihood]=VALUEOF([Overall Likelihood],"Possible"),

  IF(
   OR(
   AND(
  [Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Almost Certain"),
   [Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Unlikely")
),

  AND(  
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Almost Certain"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Possible")
),

 AND(
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Likely"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Possible")
),

 AND(
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Likely"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Likely")
),

 AND(
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Possible"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Likely")
),

 AND (
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Possible"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Almost Certain")
),

 AND(
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Unlikely"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Almost Certain")
)),

    [Overall Likelihood]=VALUEOF([Overall Likelihood],"Likely"),

IF(

 OR(

  AND(
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Almost Certain"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Likely")
),

  AND(
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Almost Certain"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Almost Certain")
),

 AND(
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Likely"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Almost Certain")
)),

     [Overall Likelihood]=VALUEOF([Overall Likelihood],"Almost Certain"),

  IF(

  OR(

  AND(
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Possible"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Rare")
),

 AND(
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Unlikely"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Unlikely")
),

 AND(
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Rare"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Possible")
)),

     [Overall Likelihood]=VALUEOF([Overall Likelihood],"Unlikely"),

IF(

OR(

  AND(

[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Unlikely"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Rare")
),

 AND(
[Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Rare"),
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Rare")
),

 AND(
    [Likelihood of Occurrence]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Occurrence],"Rare"),  
[Likelihood of Adverse Impacts]=VALUEOF([Likelihood of Adverse Impacts],"Unlikely")
)),

     [Overall Likelihood]=VALUEOF([Overall Likelihood],"Rare")
     )
    )
   )
  )
 )
```

Comment: If any of the answers have helped you, feel free to upvote and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting a value in a valuelist field, use:

```
VALUEOF([Overall Likelihood],"Possible")
```

instead of:

```
[Overall Likelihood]=VALUEOF([Overall Likelihood],"Possible")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, the calculation is in Overall Likelihood itself, which in turn is a Values list field. I did tried adding a temp value but nothing was returned. Also, I had the "Display Error" option enabled since the start but still the field remains blank.

Comment: Did you consider the possibility that maybe none of the conditions are satisfying?